# Remove ActiveStorage routes from Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I removed ActionStorage from `config/application.rb` yet I see these routes when I run `rake routes | less`.

I have nothing set up on my `/config/routes.rb`...

```
                   Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
       rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Anyone know how I can remove these?

Answer (score 12):

Two changes are needed to remove the ActiveStorage routes from an existing Rails app:

First, in `config/application.rb`, comment out `active_storage/engine` and `action_text/engine`:

```rb
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
# require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
# require "action_text/engine"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Then, in each `environment` config file (e.g. `config/development.rb`), comment out `config.active_storage.service`:

```rb
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
# config.active_storage.service = :local
```

This will remove the ActiveStorage routes:

```
$ rails routes
You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

For more information about routes, see the Rails guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.
```

Comment: in rails 6, I also need to comment the `require 'action_mailbox/engine'` to remove these routes.

Comment: can't understand, why rails inject these routes by default.
someone might want to upload files, without these routes.

There should be a way, to remove routes without removing all the engine.

Answer (score 7):

Set the `draw_routes` config to false on your application.rb config file https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/439d4995c1dab475b576fcb19ea95ae37e0ed222/guides/source/configuring.md#configuring-active-storage

```
config.active_storage.draw_routes = false
```

EDIT: as of now, the current stable release (6.0-stable) does not support this option, it's on the master branch and should work on the next release

Comment: As I understand now, that config option is not on the stable release, it's on the master branch and it will work on next releases, I don't think you can skip those routes as of now without hacking the code (which I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: This is the best answer as it allows you to keep using ActiveStorage but remove the routes when you don't need them. Other answers make ActiveStorage non-functional completely.

Answer (score 5):

There is an "official" way to do this, which is built-in into Rails. If you create new project with

```
$ rails new dummy_project --skip-active-storage
```

you can find in the newly created `config/application.rb` exactly what you need (Rails 6.0.1 but works since 5.2):

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
# require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
# require "action_mailbox/engine"
# require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Replace `require 'rails/all'` with the above snippet and you should be good to go.

Comment: With an existing project, it might be worth remove the items in the schema + any existing active record migrations

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda dumb, but for some reason deleting the `config/storage.yml` also got rid of those routes.

Comment: Well - I don't have `config/storage.yml` (application migrated to Rails 5.3 from 5.0) file but the unwanted routes show up anyway.